# How do I get the document root of my development server with cmd prompt?

Tags: php

when I create a development server on command prompt using `php -S localhost:4000`, unlike the youtube tutorial i am following, command prompt doesn't return me the document root.

Tutorial output:

```
PHP 7.4.0 Development Server (http://localhost:4000) started
Listening on http://localhost:4000
Document root is ______
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
```

My output is just:

```
PHP 7.4.0 Development Server (http://localhost:4000) started
```

This is the video tutorial i am using:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK_JCtrrv-c&t=932s

Comment: CMD has nothing to do with your program. NOTE it says to Ctrl+C to exit PHP.

Comment: why don't i get the document root when i took the same steps?